# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail + mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am executing following mulesoft code for FTP to File transfer.
Got source code from here : 
[read file from SFTP and dump to local folder using mulesoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092203/read-file-from-sftp-and-dump-to-local-folder-using-mulesoft)

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp"
  xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">

<!-- This placeholder bean lets you import the properties from the sftp.properties file. -->
<spring:bean id="property-placeholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:sftp.properties"/>
</spring:bean>

<flow name="sftp2file">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="/home/test/sftp-files" user="${sftp.user}" password="${sftp.password}"> 
                <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt,*.xml"/> 
            </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/incoming" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"/> 
</flow>
```

But I am getting following error :

```
    INFO  2017-03-29 18:43:20,877 [main] org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnector: Registering listener: sftp2file on endpointUri: sftp://{user}:****@{host}:22/incoming/test
INFO  2017-03-29 18:43:20,940 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'null'. Object is: SftpMessageReceiver
INFO  2017-03-29 18:43:20,942 [main] org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver: Connecting clusterizable message receiver
ERROR 2017-03-29 18:43:21,965 [main] org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient: Error during login to {user}@{host}
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:583) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:?]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.login(SftpClient.java:147) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnectionFactory.createClient(SftpConnectionFactory.java:116) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnector.createSftpClient(SftpConnector.java:195) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnector.createSftpClient(SftpConnector.java:178) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpReceiverRequesterUtil.getAvailableFiles(SftpReceiverRequesterUtil.java:72) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver$2.doWork(SftpMessageReceiver.java:291) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver.doConnect(SftpMessageReceiver.java:280) ~[mule-transport-sftp-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.connectHandler(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:448) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageHandler.connect(AbstractTransportMessageHandler.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.registerListener(AbstractConnector.java:1299) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:105) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.startIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:92) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.startMessageSource(DefaultMuleContext.java:381) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.startPipelineMessageSources(DefaultMuleContext.java:372) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.startMessageSources(DefaultMuleContext.java:335) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:320) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:105) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:309) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:164) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:253) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:75) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:278) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.8.3.jar:?]
ERROR 2017-03-29 18:43:21,969 [main] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Trying to reconnect to SFTP server sftp://{user}:****@{host}:22/incoming/test. Root Exception was: Error during login to {user}@{host}: Algorithm negotiation fail. Type: class java.io.IOException
ERROR 2017-03-29 18:43:21,971 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.sftp.{host}.22.incoming.test"
INFO  2017-03-29 18:43:21,978 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
```

Is there a way to configure inbound SFTP which will handle SSH issues?

Answer (score 2):

The mulesoft server that I am using is "3.8.3 EE".
This has older version of JSCH jar (jsch-0.1.51.jar).

Replace the jar with the latest one (jsch-0.1.54.jar)
OR
Add a pom dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103176/804521) to your other question?

SFTP component uses [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) under the hood. The documentation for jsch states following:

> JSch is in pure Java, but it depends on JavaTM Cryptography Extension
>   (JCE)

[here](http://suhothayan.blogspot.de/2012/05/how-to-install-java-cryptography.html) is a short description on how to install JCE.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of SFTP configured to the host, to which your SFTP connector connects, and the access permissions of the directory in which file should be placed.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server